# Add a letter in the middle of a Text in every Line, Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a huge amount of lines containing this for example this text:
OU111_DI_Z006_1

Note that some chars are different in every line, represented by @. Like this: OU@@@_@@_Z0@@__@

How can I use the search replace function to add the char X before Z ?

Like this: OU111_DI_XZ006_1

Comment: Your question is unclear. "char X in between Z and 0" and "OU111_DI_XZ006_1" are not the same. Which is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant X before Z. Like the example i noted above.

Comment: Then please [edit] and correct your question.

Comment: Done. First time here ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In replace window mark *Regular expression* and

*Find what:* `(OU..._.._)(Z0.._.)`

*Replace with:* `\1X\2`

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your data.  Are the characters "OU" and "Z0" unique to showing the start of each substring... or can these randomly show up (e.g. OU222_Z0_Z055..)?

If they are UNIQUE and cannot possibly show up anywhere except as the start of each substring, then a simple regex can work very generically:

```
Find:  (OU.*)(Z0.*)
Replace:  \1X\2
```

Here, you are grouping everything (.*) that starts with OU as "\1".  And, grouping everything starting Z0 as "\2".  (The brackets create the groups.)

The replace string is just putting an X between groups 1 and 2.

NOTE:  this is very similar to marbel82's answer, except this is more generic, because you're not specifying how many underscores and characters there must exist.

..

If however, that OU and Z0 are not unique markers, then you need to understand your data better to build a generic regex for its characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. The answers from both you and Marbel82 works like a charm!